# How to accept credit card info (and send money to credit card) without PCI compliance?

Tags: translation, payment-gateway, payment-processing, pci-compliance

Here are our requirements:

1. **Send money to our users' credit cards.** This is a unique requirement that many payment systems don't support.  We essentially need to be able to grant a bonus/reward (sort of like a refund but without a preceding purchase).
2. **Avoid stringent PCI compliance requirements.**  We're fine with paying a 3rd party to store the credit card info; we'd rather not deal with quarterly audits.
3. **Credit card form must be translatable into English, Chinese, Korean, and Russian.**
4. **Credit card form must appear within our site and look like the rest of our site.**
5. **Fees must be reasonable.**

Apparently Moneris satisfies everything except #3.  But that might be a deal breaker for us.

Know of any other gateways I should explore?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you cannot 'refund' a credit card that you have not charged a higher amount.  Sounds like you probably have a very uphill battle.

Anytime you try to remit money to a credit card, you will be asked to reference the previous CHARGE transaction or you will not be able to process the credit transaction.

Any chance the people you need to pay could all become paypal members so they can be paid?  Paypal has a very slick little interface to allow you to pay other paypal members in batches - real fast, real easy, real easy to code.  Most folks will rush to join paypal if it means that what they have to do to get paid - all you need to know to pay them is their paypal login email address.

Comment: We already accept Paypal but want to start accepting credit cards directly so that we can offer this "bonus" feature (and not require that our users do an extra step of transferring funds from Paypal to somewhere else).  Also, Moneris claims that they have negotiated #1 with the credit card companies and have collateral on the line to insure the credit card companies. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of issuing charges back to a customer's card, have you considered placing credits on their account instead? It ends up being cheaper for you (no transaction fees!), and it encourages to keep the customer with you longer.

A change in this requirement would make it very simple to use something like Recurly.com, whee I work.